# App engine automatic_scaling configuration

Tags: google-app-engine, autoscaling, cost-management

I'm trying to reduce my Google App Engine bill by setting the `automatic_scaling` parameters. In average, my app has between 7-10 instances running, where 2 or 3 of them are idle. But sometimes, like between 3 and 6am in the chart attached, the difference between active and idle instances is ridiculously large. Also, I want to reduce the number of active instances increasing the response time for the final user (setting `min_pending_latency` and `max_pending_latency`). But, until now, none of these settings are doing any effect.

This is my app.yaml configuration:

```
automatic_scaling:
  min_pending_latency: 250ms
  max_pending_latency: 750ms
  max_idle_instances: 2
```

[image: Instances]

Answer (score 7):

Setting both `min_pending_latency` *and* `max_pending_latency` sends mixed messages to the autoscaler.

More generally, you can tweak the autoscaler to *either* contain your costs (set a low value for `max_idle_instances` and/or a high one for `min_pending_latency`), *or* to improve your scalability -- that is, keep latency low for surges of traffic (set a high value for `min_idle_instances` and/or a low one for `max_pending_latency`).

**Don't** mix the two kinds of tweaks -- such "mixed messages", in my experience, never result in good effects on either costs, or latency during a surge.

And yes, I **am** working to have this fundamental bit of information become part of Google Cloud Platform's official docs -- it's just taking longer than I hoped, which is why, meanwhile, I am posting this answer.

A more advanced alternative, if you're very certain about your patterns of traffic over time, possibilities of surges, and so forth, is to switch from auto-scaled modules to basic-scaled or even manual-scaled ones, writing your own code to start and terminate instances via the [Modules API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.modules.modules).

Alhough, I have to admit, this never worked optimally for me, for modules dedicated to serving user traffic (as opposed to task-queues or cron-based "backend" work) -- my users' surges and time patterns never were as predictable going forward, as analyzing past records tantalizingly suggested. So, in the end, I always went back (for user traffic servicing) to good old auto-scaling, perhaps with the modest tweaks *either* to reduce costs, *or* to improve scalability, as I recommend above.

Comment: So, do you think this is a good configuration to contain costs?

`automatic_scaling:
  min_pending_latency: 500ms
  max_idle_instances: 2`

Comment: @JavierMarín, yes, I believe it would likely reduce costs compared to default `auto` scaling (depending on the shape and frequency of your surges in use).